# Possible places where table names will be used in a mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to log the tables that a particular query might affect inside a DB wrapper function where all the DB calls will pass through.

I can't create a view or a transaction and execute the query and infer it from the resultset since it will increase the application performance time which I can't afford.

Instead I am trying to infer it from the query itself like table names will be the next word after 'FROM,JOIN,INSERT INTO' clauses. Is there any other places table names might be used in a MYSQL query?

Comment: They could appear pretty much anywhere, considering the subquery abilities of MySQL.

Comment: And those keywords mentioned may show up in string literals, or as delimited identifiers.

Comment: You could assume that complex subqueries are not used and I am not looking for a exact solution. A crude solution is enough and that's why I am trying to do the above way.